# Using makeWith in combination with mocking

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5.6, mockery

In my code I'm using `makeWith` to resolve dependencies.
In my tests I'm creating a mock that should be resolved in the code by calling the `makeWith`. However it's not the case.

```
App::make('App\Item'); //ok: returns mock
App::makeWith('App\Item', ['name' => 'apple'];//not ok: doesn't return the mock but the class to be used outside the test environment
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

To set mock object use

```
App::offsetSet('App\Item', $itemMock);
```

Now

```
App::makeWith('App\Item', ['name' => 'apple']);
```

Returns `$itemMock`